# Understanding Haskell accessor functions

Tags: haskell, accessor

I'm reading up on Monad tutorials, and the one I'm working on now is http://www.muitovar.com/monad/moncow.xhtml , but I ran on a problem with the state Monad, or to be more precise the runState accessor function.

The type is defined as

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: (s -> (a,s)) }
```

and it's called e.g.

```
runState (chncasewst3 'e' 'd' 'f') False
```

I don't know how to read the definition for getting to the second line, especially because of the "State s a" part. If it where "State a s", I could deduce that the accessor has been curried 'as far' as the 's'.

So the question is; how to read the type definition so that I could see how to call the accessor function in this situation, and if possible how to read accessor functions per se.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you have a data type defined as

```
data T a b = MkT { getA :: a, getB :: b }
```

read it like

```
data T a b = MkT a b
```

with two helper functions defined automatically:

```
getA :: (T a b) -> a
getA (MkT x _) = x

getB :: (T a b) -> b
getB (MkT _ y) = y
```

When you apply `getA` to the value of `T`, the result is of type `a`.

Now your `State` type consists of only one element, which type is a function (`:: s -> (a, s)`). `runState` converts a value of type `State s a` to a function of this type.

```
ghci> :t runState
runState :: State s a -> s -> (a, s)
```

Every time you apply `runState` to the value of type `State s a`, the result is a function of type `s -> (a,s)`. And the first argument of this function is an initial value of the state variable (of type `s`).

In the tutorial example,

- `chncasewst3 'e' 'd' 'f'` has type `State Bool String`.
- So, `runState (chncasewst3 'e' 'd' 'f')` has type `Bool -> (String, Bool)`.
- So, `runState (chncasewst3 'e' 'd' 'f') False` has type `(String, Bool)`.

Further reading:

- [Learn You a Haskell: Making Our Own Types and Typeclasses](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses)
- [RWH: Defining Types, Streamlining Functions](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/defining-types-streamlining-functions.html)